# Oracle ADF mobile website not loading on Windows Phone 8

Tags: html, oracle, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10, mobile-website

I have created a mobile website using Oracle's ADF. When I view it on Internet Explorer 10 (Windows Phone 8) website just shows a blank page.

When I change the Website Preference on IE10(Windows Phone 8) to Desktop Version, the mobile site works perfectly, But when i change Website Preference back to Mobile Version the website shows a blank/white page.

Any reasons for this? How will i be able to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you test it by sending custom user agent strings from a desktop browser? Does a brand new app work as expected if you started fresh?

Comment: How do i send custom user agent strings? Fresh application also does not work in mobile browser :(

Comment: I don't think IE10 has the feature directly, so I'd use fiddler to send a request with the agent string matching mobile to see what happens.